# What's the meaning of instantiation unit in C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, instantiation

C++11 §2.2 Phases of translation, 8th phrase.
Translated translation units and instantiation units are combined as follows. 
What's the exact meaning of "instantiation unit"?

Answer (score 2):

Instantiation units are template instantiations (implicit and explicit).

For example, for this template :

```
template < typename T >
struct A
{
};
```

this :

```
template class A<int>;
```

with addition of the above template declaration and definition, is one instantiation unit.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning hasn't changed since the C++98 standard, since this was the original C++ compilation model - instantiation units are separate files where template instantiations encountered by the compiler in a TU are stored, so that each template instantiation is compiled only once per program.

To quote [IBM compiler documentation](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/compiler/ref/ruopttrg.htm) on their `-qtemplateregistry` option,

> When a compilation unit instantiates a new instance for the first time, the compiler creates this instance and keeps the record in a registry file. [...] When another compilation unit references the same instantiation and uses the same registry file as in the previous compilation unit, this instance will not be instantiated again. Thus, only one copy is generated for the entire program.

Oracle has a [more extensive documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkage.html#scrolltoc) on the C++ template compilation model.

GCC doesn't have an automatic repository, but [the docs seem to imply that similar results can be obtained](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html) by compiling with `-frepo` and running `collect2`

Comment: The Standard says in [lex.phases]/1/8 "All the required
instantiations are performed to produce instantiation units. [*Note:* These are similar to translated
translation units, but contain no references to uninstantiated templates and no template definitions.
— *end note*]" IMHO that note suggests that instantiation units are not separate files, but translated TUs with "resolved" templates.

Comment: @DyP I have a hard time interpreting that note that way, but I would agree that the concept is not sufficiently specified, and was probably  only put there as part of the 1998 `export` template wishful thinking.